# compare multiple files rows by two columns, match the first compare the second

Tags: awk, file-comparison

I have two input files like these:

file1

```
ABC001;text;text;5.00;text;text;;20/06/2020;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar4325.jpg
ABC002;text;text;15.20;text;text;;4/12/2021;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar545.jpg
ABC003;text;text;10.00;text;text;;24/07/2021;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar6y6.jpg
ABC004;text;text;4.90;text;text;;31/12/2021;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar5464.jpg
ABC007;text;text;10.30;text;text;;3/12/2021;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar45tgv.jpg
ABC010;text;text;9.00;text;text;;20/12/2021;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar2345f.jpg
```

file2 ("rounded" prices are without .00)

```
ABC001;text;text;6
ABC002;text;text;15.20
ABC003;text;text;10
ABC004;text;text;5.50
ABC005;text;text;25
ABC007;text;text;10.50
ABC010;text;text;9
```

output desired:

```
ABC001;text;text;5.00;text;text;;20/06/2020;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar4325.jpg
ABC004;text;text;4.90;text;text;;31/12/2021;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar5464.jpg
ABC007;text;text;10.30;text;text;;3/12/2021;http://www.domain.com/img/foobar45tgv.jpg
```

The rows need to match the first column and then compare matched rows "price" column (fifth) it the price is numerically different I would like to extract only the
the rows from the file1.

I use this (GNU Awk 4.0.2):

```
awk -F';' -v RS='[\r\n]+' 'FNR==NR{righe[$1]; next} $1 in righe' file1.csv file2.csv > output.csv
```

to compare two csv file but I'm not able to add the price conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pick the right columns and also first read the `file2` then `file1`, additionally you also need to compare the value part as well as well as the key part:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{ id[$1]=$4; next} ($1 in id) && id[$1]!=$4' file2 file1
```

here `$1` is used for the keys of the array *id* and `$4` are the value part.